# use rxjs to create an observable that will be connected to a web socket later

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs, observable, mediator

I am working on a web project. A web-socket is created when a user is authenticated(server only accepts authenticated users).

I want my modules(observers) to get an observable from 'server-messaging' module(service,..), even before user is authenticated.
Basically nothing is behind the observable yet.

This 'server-messaging' service abstracts away details of web-socket creation and returns an observable based on the socket.

The question is how can I create an observable that will be based on a socket(to be created later/lazy).

When the socket comes to existence, then onNext.. of observers will be called, before that nothing will be called.

In pseudo and by concept only code:

```
//interested observer.js
messagingService.observable.subscribe(observer);
...
// user is authneticated, messagingservice.js
this.observervable.onmessage = socket.onmessage;
```

Comment: Your question seems to show a lack of research on the subject. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then google rxjs websocket, then put rxjs websocket in the searchbox on SO. Then if you still haven't found what you are looking for, come back with a specific question with possibly some code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of an [AsyncSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/asyncsubject.md) and [mergeAll](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/mergeall.md) to essentially "publish" the observable from the messaging service before the socket connection is made.  Something like this:

```
// messagingService.js

// will be given the observable from the socket when
// it is ready
var socketSubject = new Rx.AsyncSubject();

// call flatMap to flatten the observable of observable into
// just an observable of messages
messagingService.observable = socketSubject.mergeAll();

// make the connection
messagingService.makeConnection = function(args) {
    var messageObservable = // ...

    // give the messageObservable to the socketSubject
    socketSubject.onNext(messageObservable);
    socketSubject.onComplete();
}
```

With this technique, client code can subscribe to the observable *before* the connection is ever made.